# JS detecting div height left below the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have a html markup as below:

[image]

There is a div that pretty much covers the whole height of the page. 
The height however is dynamically generated.

[image]

When user scrolls the div down and if there is 100px left of the div below the viewable screen, I want to trigger an action (for example, alert).

Because screen size varies, I need a way of simply detecting how much of div is left below the screen.

The thing is, I don't want to constantly measure the height change as that may be "hard" on the user end.

One idea is that maybe I will have a "hidden" div at the end of this main div, and when it is in view point, then I will trigger an action.

As you can see, I am not sure what the best way is for this purpose.

If you need clarification, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - (div.offsetTop + div.scrollHeight) > -100) {
    alert('Less than 100px of div remains below viewport');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

- `window.pageYOffset` is current scroll position from top,
- `window.innerHeight` is height of the viewport,
- `div.offsetTop` is `div`'s position from top,
- `div.scrollHeight` is height of the `div`.

Entire `if` stands for number of pixels scrolled beyond bottom of the `div`. And `-100` beyond the bottom means 100px left to it.